# How did i-r0k listen in on Parzival's conversations at the dance club?

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-player-one

How does i-r0k listen to Parzival's conversation at the dance club?  I noticed that several avatars ask to get their picture with Parzival and one of them scans him and sends something to i-r0k from their inventory but what did they do from that action?

How did that give i-r0k the ability to hack/listen to Parzival's conversations?  How come i-r0k wasn't able to listen in for the rest of the movie?  How come it only lasted in the dance club?

Comment: Seems to me the cat-woman is just sending the photo of Parzival to i-rOk to let him know where to find him. As for listening in - some kind of spy software, and it's about the only time that i-rOk is anywhere near Parzival before the final fight in the castle